# нотификации-уведомления

Tags: javascript

взял для решения `notify.js`
и у меня проблема добавления уведомлений в ВИДИМОЙ области окна браузера, то есть я хочу вывести уведомление в левом нижнем углу окна (хотя ещё есть скролл ниже) либо в правом верхнем углу. Ещё раз как по координатам вывести уведомление поверх моего `body` в видимой части окна? Спасибо.

На данный момент выводится уведомление в теле `body` и соответственно в самом низу блоков :(

```
$('body').notify(
  "Notification, Success", 
  { position:"left-bottom" }
);
```

https://notifyjs.com/ `Notification API`

`Notification API` использовать не хочется по причине того что пользователь может проигнорировать выбор включить или отключить уведомление на сайте. Поэтому подобие `notify.js` практичнее.

Comment: добавь ссылку на библиотеку, которую используешь

Comment: Добавил, и обновил на свой ответ.

Comment: почему нужно именно на элементе `body`, а не глобально?

Comment: да можно просто $.notify.... разницы нет

Comment: вообще-то есть.

Comment: Конкретно, в чём же?)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок добился ПОЧТИ желаемого эффекта:

```
$('body').notify( "Notification, Success", 
       { position:"left-bottom" 
}).offset({top: 0, left 1000});
```

Т.е. отображение будет ПОВЕРХ и не зависимо от скролла, т.е. будет всегда по координатам выше справа вверху. 
**Какие ещё есть** способы решения, т.к. этот способ не очень мне нравится, но хотя бы работает. И ещё при таком способе возникает ошибка мол offset is not a function :(

Comment: если возникает ошибка - значит решение _не_ работает

Comment: Всё прекрасно работает, разобрался сам хоть и времени ушло, а вам писать конкретнее, а не флудить. Вопрос закрываю.

Comment: _ошибка мол offset is not a function_ - намекает, что если убрать вызов offset - ничего не поменяется, только ошибка пропадет. Следовательно приведенный код ничем не отличается от того. что был в вопросе.

Comment: Просто напишите один из вариантов решения, а если мне не верите и основываетесь на теорию просто запустите вместе с этим плагином и создайте простой div результат вас значит удивит! удачи. Странно что набрали высокий рейтинг, т.к. вы заблуждаетесь.

Comment: От заблуждений никто не застрахован. Обязанность предоставить [mcve] лежит на авторе вопроса, чтобы можно было увидеть, что именно у него работает не так.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, позиция указывается через пробел

```
 { position:"left bottom" }
```

Так-же неправильно то, что вы вызываете функцию из `body`, нужно так:

```
$.notify( "Notification", 
  { position:"left bottom" }
);
```

Тип нотификейшона тоже указан неверно, для него нужны отдельные кавычки:

```
$.notify( "Notification", "success",
  { position:"left bottom" }
);
```